# JPA: deleteAll entries and then recreate single entries in one transaction

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

i have the problem, that I want to delete all entries from one table and then recreate single items with the same IDs as deleted ones from scratch. This should be in one transaction, so that the table is never empty.

Hint: I use Spring Batch and delete the talbe by a chunk listener beforeChunk (which is inside the transaction), the reader/writer runs afterwards to persist the new version of the data.

Currentely, if I do that, I recieve this error:

`Encountered an error executing step importXXXXX in job jobXXXX java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot merge an Entity that has been removed`

Stack Trace:

```
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.registerObjectForMergeCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:1070) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:564) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:313) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3521) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeCloneWithReferences(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:387) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3481) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.mergeInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:553) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:530) ~[eclipselink-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6]
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.doWrite(JpaItemWriter.java:104) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter.write(JpaItemWriter.java:83) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Do you have an idea to persit the entry although it is already deleted in this transaction.

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't seem possible to me with JPA. Have you tried reusing entities and only delete those that aren't reused? This also seems much more efficient since you only need to do an update and not a delete and insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) has the following to say in section *3.2.4.1 Merging Detached Entity State*:

> If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail).

It also says in section *3.2.1 Persisting an Entity Instance*:

> If X is a removed entity, it becomes managed.

And further down in section *3.2.3 Synchronization to the Database*:

> If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
>
> [...]
>
> - If X is a removed entity, it is removed from the database. No cascade options are relevant.

So it doesn't seem possible what you are trying to do with JPA. One work around might be entity reuse as suggested in my comment.

Comment: Thanks, this is interessting. Do you know a way to mark an instance as "undeleted"?

Comment: @SScholl Sorry, I didn't get all the details from the spec on the first try. So it seems now it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks anyway @SpaceTrucker